# How to make the scrolling link in main menu to be active on click only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a website by wordpress using "The7" theme.

in the main menu i have three anchor links that links to sections in the homepage, i have a problem these links have "active" class ((i think it's because of the theme))

[Here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZJX.jpg)

**I need these links to be active on click only**

i tried to insert a js script to the header to avoid these links having "active" class

```
$(function() {
      var $navLIs = $('header.header-bar ul li a')
      $navLIs.click(function() {
        $navLIs.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are inserting the script after the header (html content) has loaded.

If so, you can try something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <!-- styles, meta tags, title, etc -->
   <head>
   <body>
       <header class='header'>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a class='active item-one'>item one</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a class='active item-one'>item one</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a class='active item-one'>item one</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </header>
       <!-- rest of your html -->
       <script>
           (function() {
               function removeActiveClassFromMenuItems() {
                   const activeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
                   activeItems.forEach(item => {
                       item.classList.remove('active');
                   });
                }
                removeActiveClassFromMenuItems(); //Removes active class
            })();
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```